# What are the potential implications of a deep call stack in Perl?

Tags: perl

- I was told that the following portion of code is deeply recursive. However I don't understand how - can someone explain?
- If so, what are the associated implications?

#### Note:

Trivial example

```
            check:
            # Grab some data held in a file
            while ((ReadFile ()) != 0 ) { 
                    if ((checkSomething ()) != 1) {
                            # value found, check file again
                            next check;
                    } else {
                            blah ($doo, $foo);
                    }
            }
```

#### Update:

- Thank you for the correction.
- What are the implications of the following, in terms of memory consumption - this is not recursion as far as I understand and after reviewing other questions:

  ```
  sub D {
          ..
  }
  sub C {
          D ();
  }
  sub B {
          C ();
  }
  sub A {
          while (true) {
                  B ();
          }
  }
  ```

Comment: Is that code within a function at all? Is that function named `blah`?

Comment: What? Is this example code inside a subroutine called `blah` or something?

Comment: No. It is inside an if statement. blah () is contained in another sub

Comment: On what basis do you believe that the person telling you that code is recursive, was correct?

Comment: Lol, that code has nothing to do with recursion

Comment: Hi Greg, sorry I'm new to perl, I wasn't sure because I'm not calling blah within blah and I explicitly return from ReadFile and CheckSomething.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second example is also not an example of recursion. That's just an example of what I would informally call "chained subroutine calls" - I don't believe there's a formal term for it. Recursion requires that a subroutine call itself, either directly or through some set of intermediaries.

For example, if subroutine D had a call in it to A, B, or C under certain conditions, that would be recursion.

As for deep call stacks, the answer is it depends on:

- how deep
- how many arguments you're passing in each one
- how much memory your program can allocate

Each time you call a subroutine, it adds a new frame on the call stack. That frame remains until the subroutine completes. The size of this stack frame depends primarily on the length of your arguments list, plus some fixed overhead.

So in this case, you'd have a stack frame with four elements.

If your call chain gets too deep and each entry has a long list of arguments, you'll eventually run out of space for the call stack. This is called a Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: iirc 4 frames on the stack, that is each time a function call is made, a new frame is created in the stack?

Comment: Yes, each time a subroutine is called, a new frame is created. When the subroutine completes, the frame is removed. So it doesn't matter (for this discussion) how many total subroutine calls occur in the whole life of the program, but rather how many occur in a single chain.

Comment: we don't have stack overflows in perl. perl's call stack is on the heap. endless recursion will cause swapping and then out of memory errors. same for endless looping with lexicals in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, your code isn't recursive, so don't worry about it. However, it'll be cleaner and easier to read if you eliminate the useless `if` branch by making the condition for the `else` branch the only one, and drop the icky label:

```
while ((ReadFile ()) != 0 ) { 
    if ((checkSomething ()) == 1) {
        blah ($doo, $foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no recursion in that code.

Your code may have recursion, but it's not shown in the code you offered.

Comment: It is within an IF statement. blah () is contained within another sub. As far as I understand recursion - if you call A() when you are inside A().

Comment: You didn't show that.  Even after the edit in your question, there's still no recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JS Bangs, but another alternative to the icky label would be to use a continue statement instead of the "next check".  JS Bangs is the best for this code, but continue statements have their place.

Comment: This is Perl, which uses `next` for the same purpose as `continue` in C and many other languages.